# How to colorize a formula in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

I created a formula in Crystal Report to format an uppercase field into proper case, here's the code

namePropercase (name of formula)

> propercase({spMSR;1.name})

Now, is there anyway to format also its font color into orange, as requirement? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way.

Right click on the formula... And go to font there you can provide the font color to change

Answer (score 0):

If {field} > {field} then
RGB(255,128,64)
else
crNoColor

I'm not exactly sure what you are doing in your report but here is an example of changing the font color with an if statement. Also there is no crOrange that I know of, so I use the RGB color code.